# event.preventDefault doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, preventdefault

So im trying to stop a form from refreshing the page and this is the code i'm using:

```
$("#getName").submit(function(refresh) {
    refresh.preventDefault();
    $("#p22").fadeOut(50);
    $("#p23").fadeIn(800);
    document.getElementById("p23").innerHTML = "Oh " + userName + ", alright i wont forget that!";

})
```

I can't seem to get this working properly....

id = getName   - is the form id

Comment: any error in your console

Comment: What does console say? And the fourth line of your callback can be shortened: `$('#p23').html("Oh " + userName + ", alright i wont forget that!")`

Comment: `userName` is not defined in the above code. Can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: Provide minimalistic JSFiddle sample that reconstruct your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6462306/986160

Try this:

```
$("#getName").submit(function(refresh) {
    $("#p22").fadeOut(50);
    $("#p23").fadeIn(800);
    $("#p23").html("Oh " + userName + ", alright i wont forget that!");
    return false;
})
```

By returning false is like refresh.preventDefault() and refresh.stopPropagation() together ;) See details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/986160

Answer (score 1):

I got this sample code of the jQuery documentation and it seems to work fine (it alert's but then doesn't link to `destination.html`. Everything seems fine in your code, it's probably something different you're looking for.

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

```js
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

Comment: Edited it for you. @laffuste

Answer (score 0):

Returning false will not validate your form and your page will not be refreshed.

```
$("#getName").submit(function(refresh) {
    refresh.preventDefault();
    $("#p22").fadeOut(50);
    $("#p23").fadeIn(800);
    document.getElementById("p23").innerHTML = "Oh " + userName + ", alright i wont forget that!";
    return false;
})
```

Comment: return false; is like refresh.preventDefault(); and refresh.stopPropagation(); so you don't need the refresh.preventDefault() on the top. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/986160