# Inline-Javascript for Hidden Input Field Isn't functioning correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm no expert in JS, but I'm trying to make a function assess the values in my first select fields, and then return the value to a hidden input field. Doesn't work, JS is definitely messed up, please help!

```
/** Usually form leads to sheet/fields which use the data, 
    but for example just used # **/

<form action="#" method="get" name="iceform" id="iceform" onsubmit="iceform_submit()">
  <div class="icecream">

    <div class="flavorType">
      <select name="flavorType" class="flavor-type empty" id = "flavor-type">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Flavor Type Desired</option>
        <option value="2">Frozen Treats</option>
        <option value="5">Soft Served</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="flavor">
      <select name="flavorAmount" class="flavor empty" id='flavor-amount'>
        <option value="0" disabled selected>flavor Amount Desired</option>
        <option value="750">$750</option>
        <option value="800">$800</option>
        <option value="850">$850</option>
        <option value="900">$900</option>
        <option value="950">$950</option>
        <option value="1000">$1000</option>
        <option value="1250">$1250</option>
        <option value="1500">$1500</option>
        <option value="1750">$1750</option>
        <option value="2000">$2000</option>
        <option value="2250">$2250</option>
        <option value="2500">$2500</option>
        <option value="2750">$2750</option>
        <option value="3000">$3000</option>
        <option value="3250">$3250</option>
        <option value="3500">$3500</option>
        <option value="3750">$3750</option>
        <option value="4000">$4000</option>
        <option value="4250">$4250</option>
        <option value="4500">$4500</option>
        <option value="5000">$5000</option>
        <option value="5500">$5500</option>
        <option value="6000">$6000</option>
        <option value="6500">$6500</option>
        <option value="7000">$7000</option>
        <option value="7500">$7500</option>
        <option value="8000">$8000</option>
        <option value="8500">$8500</option>
        <option value="9000">$9000</option>
        <option value="9500">$9500</option>
        <option value="10000">$10000</option>
      </select>
    </div>
   <br>
    <!-- Upon submit call js function -->
    <div class="form-button">
      <input type='submit' class="submit tp-button green big :hover.green" value="Continue">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="flavorTypeId" value=''>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    /** Function Called to define/return newflavortype **/
  function CheckFlavorTypeID(flavor_amount, flavor_type) {
    var newflavortype = flavor_type;
    switch (parseInt(flavor_type, radix)) {
    case 2:
        /** Frozen Treats **/
      switch (parseInt(flavor_amount, radix)) {
      case 750:
      case 800:
      case 850:
      case 900:
      case 950:
        newflavortype = 10;
        break;
      case 1000:
      case 1250:
      case 1500:
      case 1750:
      case 2000:
      case 2250:
      case 2500:
      case 2750:
      case 3000:
      case 3250:
      case 3500:
      case 3750:
      case 4000:
      case 4250:
      case 4500:
        newflavortype = 11;
        break;
      case 5000:
      case 5500:
      case 6000:
      case 6500:
      case 7000:
      case 7500:
      case 8000:
      case 8500:
      case 9000:
      case 9500:
      case 10000:
        newflavortype = 12;
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      /* Soft Served */
      switch (parseInt(flavor_amount, radix)) {
      case 750:
      case 800:
      case 850:
      case 900:
      case 950:
        newflavortype = 3;
        break;
      case 1000:
      case 1250:
      case 1500:
      case 1750:
      case 2000:
      case 2250:
      case 2500:
      case 2750:
      case 3000:
      case 3250:
      case 3500:
      case 3750:
      case 4000:
      case 4250:
      case 4500:
        newflavortype = 6;
        break;
      case 5000:
      case 5500:
      case 6000:
      case 6500:
      case 7000:
      case 7500:
      case 8000:
      case 8500:
      case 9000:
      case 9500:
      case 10000:
        newflavortype = 7;
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
      break;
    default: newflavortype = 3;
      break;
    }
    return newflavortype;
  }
    /** The function that submits the form and defines flavorTypeId - value (hidden) **/
    function iceform_submit() {
      var iceform = document.getElementById('iceform');
      var flavorA = document.getElementById('flavor-amount').value;
      var flavorT = document.getElementById('flavor-type').value;
      iceform.flavorTypeId.value = CheckFlavorTypeID(flavorA, flavorT);
      iceform.submit();
    }
  </script>
</form>
```

Comment: `In other topic` You should consider to store all the `cases` in array or other data structure your code look like spaguetti code. and its hard to read.

Comment: that's a great idea, though I wasn't entirely sure how to create arrays in js, I am familiar with jquery though. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace input submit to this:

```
 <input type='button' onclick="iceform_submit()" class="submit tp-button green big :hover.green" value="Continue">
```

and use this script and remember you do not have variable `radix` anywhere declared so i just removed it:if you are willing to use then declare it and assign some value to it then use,but i personally don't see any use of it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /** Function Called to define/return newflavortype **/
  function CheckFlavorTypeID(flavor_amount, flavor_type) {
    var newflavortype = flavor_type;
    switch (parseInt(flavor_type)) {
    case 2:
        /** Frozen Treats **/
      switch (parseInt(flavor_amount)) {
      case 750:
      case 800:
      case 850:
      case 900:
      case 950:
        newflavortype = 10;
        break;
      case 1000:
      case 1250:
      case 1500:
      case 1750:
      case 2000:
      case 2250:
      case 2500:
      case 2750:
      case 3000:
      case 3250:
      case 3500:
      case 3750:
      case 4000:
      case 4250:
      case 4500:
        newflavortype = 11;
        break;
      case 5000:
      case 5500:
      case 6000:
      case 6500:
      case 7000:
      case 7500:
      case 8000:
      case 8500:
      case 9000:
      case 9500:
      case 10000:
        newflavortype = 12;
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      /* Soft Served */
      switch (parseInt(flavor_amount)) {
      case 750:
      case 800:
      case 850:
      case 900:
      case 950:
        newflavortype = 3;
        break;
      case 1000:
      case 1250:
      case 1500:
      case 1750:
      case 2000:
      case 2250:
      case 2500:
      case 2750:
      case 3000:
      case 3250:
      case 3500:
      case 3750:
      case 4000:
      case 4250:
      case 4500:
        newflavortype = 6;
        break;
      case 5000:
      case 5500:
      case 6000:
      case 6500:
      case 7000:
      case 7500:
      case 8000:
      case 8500:
      case 9000:
      case 9500:
      case 10000:
        newflavortype = 7;
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
      break;
    default: newflavortype = 3;
      break;
    }
    return newflavortype;
  }
    /** The function that submits the form and defines flavorTypeId - value (hidden) **/
    function iceform_submit() {
      var iceform = document.getElementById('iceform');
      var flavorA = document.getElementById('flavor-amount').value;
      var flavorT = document.getElementById('flavor-type').value;
      iceform.flavorTypeId.value = CheckFlavorTypeID(flavorA, flavorT);
    //  alert(iceform.flavorTypeId.value);
      iceform.submit();
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: my hero, thank you so much XD. I know this isn't the question, but anyway to make this work with validation - which is limited to submit

Comment: @Bakajuice i did not get you.please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, html5 validation for required fields (i think) only works with input submit not input button, would using something like prevent_default with input submit work in this situation.

Comment: if you can use jquery see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462143/prevent-default-on-form-submit-jquery.because from iceform_submit() you can not pass event because it is in html.

Comment: thanks a lot @suchit ultimately I'll look into it, probably use jquery for validation

Answer (score 1):

Your function `iceform_submit` is never being called because you have a `onsubmit` attribute on your button. It should be on the form tag, (or you should use an `onClick` on the button tag instead). It is the form that gets submitted, not the button!

So your form tag should look like this;

```
<form action="#" method="get" name="iceform" id="iceform" onsubmit="iceform_submit()">
```

..and you should remove the onsubmit from the button, like this;

```
<input type='submit' class="submit tp-button green big :hover.green" value="Continue">
```

I've chosen not to comment on the rest of your code (as that was not your question), suffice to say that your switch statement could be simplified a LOT.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No good :C , the flavorTypeId still doesn't retain any values, I appreciate the help though -EDIT - I've changed the above code to reflect your answer. Thank you