# Inserting into Mysql form php with Ajax without reload page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this jQuery AJAX code that into Mysql form php. It works without reloading the page. The problem is that it When the user enters something into the form, then clicks submit, I would like to use php and ajax (with jquery). But it do not print the string in alert() . Can someone please show me how this can be achieved?

HTML :

```
<form id="students" method="post">
   <div class="row">
      <input name="a[]" value="" type="text" >
      <input name="b[]" value="" type="text"  >
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <input name="a[]" value="" type="text" >
      <input name="b[]" value="" type="text"  >
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitbutton" class="insert"/>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#students').submit(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax_insert.php',
      data: $('#students').serialize(),
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data) {
          alert('form has been posted successfully');
      }
    });
 });
</script>
```

and ajax_insert.php :

```
$a1=$_POST['a'];
$b1=$_POST['b'];

//$query_values = array();
$index=0;

foreach($a1 as $s){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO test_data(a,b) VALUES('$s','".$b1[$index]."')";

   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   if($result)
   {
     echo "1";
   }
   $index++;
}
```

Comment: what say the console log ?

Comment: you should look for `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462143/prevent-default-on-form-submit-jquery

Comment: I did add event.preventDefault(). But it's can't work

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#students').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax_insert.php',
    data: $('#students').serialize(),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
    alert('form has been posted successfully');
  }
 });
```

check official document [here](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) and learn how to use `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @HTT you can accept an answer by clicking around upvote counts.

Comment: Can you tell me know where it is?

Comment: @HTT see this answer to understand , how accepting an answer works. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: @HTT you didn't get it ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to `event.preventDefault();` in the submit event callback :

```
$('#students').submit(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax_insert.php',
    data: $('#students').serialize(),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
      alert('form has been posted successfully');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I did add event.preventDefault(). But it's can't work

Answer (score 0):

You need return valid json when use dataType: "json" in $.ajax call

Or you can use dataType: "html" without rewriting php code

Update (examples of code, that should work):

in HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#students').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax_insert.php',
      data: $('#students').serialize(),
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data) {
          if(data.result == 1) {
              alert('form has been posted successfully');
          } else {
              alert(data.error);
          }
      }
    });
 });
</script>
```

ajax_insert.php

```
$a1=$_POST['a'];
$b1=$_POST['b'];

//$query_values = array();
$index=0;
$errors = array();

foreach($a1 as $s){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO test_data(a,b) VALUES('$s','".$b1[$index]."')";

   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   if(!$result)
   {
     $errors[] = "\"$sql\"";
   }
   $index++;
}

if(!empty($errors)) {
   echo json_encode(array('result'=>0,'error'=>"Error executing following queries: \n".implode("\n", $errors)));
} else {
   echo json_encode(array('result'=>1));
}
```

Comment: how to return valid json?

Comment: use echo '{"result":"1"}'; instead of echo "1"; in your ajax_insert.php

Comment: like this :  if($result)
 {
  echo '{"result":"1"}';
 }. It isn't work

Comment: Sorry, i missed that echo actually runs two times, so, it returns not valid json. If you remove echo from the cycle and insert it at the end of script everything must works. But you need some kind of error handling when you insert data. Something like if (!$result) { echo json_encode(array('result'=>0)); exit;} and in success callback you can test if data.result is 1 or 0 end do what you want