# How can I stop an ajax form submit from refreshing page on error callback?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this ajax request that is used for login, it redirects on successful login to user dash and on fail I want it to display an alert and not refresh. Is there any way to stop the refresh?

```
$('#doctor_login').on("submit", function (e) {
frmReg = document.getElementById("doctor_login");

if (frmReg.user_name.value == "") {
    alert("<?php echo _USERNAME_EMPTY_ALERT; ?>"); frmReg.user_name.focus(); return false;
}
else if (frmReg.password.value == "") {
    alert("<?php echo _PASSWORD_IS_EMPTY; ?>"); frmReg.password.focus(); return false;
}
else {
    $.ajax({

        dataType: "html",
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../doctor/handlers/handler_ajax_login.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {

            alert('hi');
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: it seems like there should be more to the story.  For instance, is this inside of a submit click handler?  Do you need to preventDefault?

Comment: yea a couple lines got cut off, it's a submission handler for the submit button. I don't think I need to prevent default, being redirected or not is handled by the php, but when the error callback is triggered it does a refresh of the page and I don't want that. So whatever works to just stop refresh in that case.

Comment: just return false;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462143/prevent-default-on-form-submit-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a return false to prevent it.

```
 $.ajax({

    dataType: "html",
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../doctor/handlers/handler_ajax_login.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);

    },
    error: function (response) {

        alert('hi');
        return false;
    }
});
```

or use:

```
$('#doctor_login').on("submit", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
```

Then you can submit it when you want, as this will prevent it form submiting until you want it to