# Prevent default not working in ajax form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried my level best in implementing this ajax. I dont what the form's default action to happen.I give prevent default but its not working. My page form is getting submitted without ajax. When i tried on click instead of on submit the captcha validation is not working.Can someone tell whats the mistake here. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#login").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "login.php",
      data: $('#login').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        if (data == 'success') {
          location.reload();
        } else {
          $('#loginmsg').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
        }
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="<?php echo $root ?>login.php" id="login" method="post">
  <div id="loginmsg"></div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="login_email" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="login_email" placeholder="Email address">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="login_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="login_password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <img src="common/captcha/captcha.php" id="captcha" height="50" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src='common/captcha/captcha.php?'+Math.random();document.getElementById('captcha-form').focus()" id=change-image title="Click here to refresh captcha code"><i class="fa fa-refresh refresh-sec"></i></a>
    <div class="form-item inline">
      <div class="captcha-block">
        <p class="comment-form-captcha"><input name="captcha" type="text" id="captcha-form" autocomplete="off" class="form-text contact-captcha" maxlength="6" required="required" /></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="theme_button color1">
          Log in
          </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462143/prevent-default-on-form-submit-jquery

Comment: its not working in my case :(

Comment: @freedomn-m Why change the whole script behavior when `.submit()` should work just fine ? @Sarath: Try adding `e.stopPropagation();` right after your `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: I tried on click function too as i mentioned in question in that case my captcha is not generating a session

Comment: How does your "captcha validation" work?  There's nothing in the code you've included.  Is there another .js file for it?  It's possible it's adding its *own* submit handler which is kicking in before yours.  Can you confirm your submit handler is being hit (add an alert or console.log)

Comment: captcha is a php function not able to add it here

Comment: Should work fine as shown. Does form exist at page load time? Is `id=login` used more than once in the page? Are any errors thrown in browser console?

Comment: Is there a javascript component? (you're correct, the php part shouldn't be relevant)

Comment: id=login is only used once

Comment: Can see the form does not submit in your demo. Something else is different

Comment: I was working in another website which i done. What i did is just took it from there.It seems so strange for me

Comment: Are you sure the form isn't loaded by ajax? Put an `alert($('#login').length)` .. should not be zero

Comment: @charlietfl Stack Snippet is sandboxed, afaik you can't submit a form with it anyway ..?

Comment: @Teemu irregardless the basic code works https://jsfiddle.net/j4hrja77/

Comment: i tried using alert($('#login').length);  but it again get skipped

Comment: @Teemu also seems snippets don't prevent default submit, just tested with a simple form

Comment: You can check the test site here : http://test.foragespiders.com/modeling/

Comment: If the only thing you need to do is to prevent the default action, you can supply value as false instead of a function: $('#login').submit(false);

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
 <button type="button" class="theme_button color1">Log in</button>
```

instead of

```
<button type="submit" class="theme_button color1">Log in</button>
```

and change the form submit to

```
     $(document).on("click",".theme_button ", function(){


        });
```

you have two id in your html

```
<a class="topline-button" id="login" data-target="#" href="./" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login
</a>


<form role="form" action="login.php" id="login" method="post">

</form>
```

Comment: Without type submit also my form is getting submitted

Comment: I already tried on click even. in that case my captcha is not working.

Comment: I am not getting any variable values of form in the next page.Thats the issue i spotted after alerting.

Comment: let me know this method of passing data is correct. ? data: $('#login').serialize(),

Comment: try with `data:{"formdata":$('#login').serialize()}`

Comment: i tried to print $_REQUEST['email']; and $_POST['email']; that itself is not coming

Comment: try to print `print_r($_REQUEST);`.  or `print_r($_REQUEST['formdata']);`

Comment: you have 2 same id in you html. please change that.

Comment: check my answer.. `id="login"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click','#login' ,function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "login.php",
      data: $('#login').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        if (data == 'success') {
          location.reload();
        } else {
          $('#loginmsg').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
        }
      }

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I already tried on click even. in that case my captcha is not working