# Weird JQuery location.reload() behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my javascript code that will be invoked when user click the **Browse** button in HTML:

```
function run(){
console.log('run();')
document.getElementById('csv_file_upload').addEventListener('change', read_csv, false);

$('#csv_file_upload').click(function() {
    location.reload();
    console.log('reload();');
});}
```

And this is part of my HTML code:

```
<div id="dvImportSegments" class="fileupload ">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload your CSV File</legend>
            <input type="file" name="File Upload" id="csv_file_upload" accept=".csv" onclick="run();" />
   </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="data-display"></div>
```

Below is the screenshot to specify my question:

1)This is how my page looks like:
[image: image-01]

2)And when I click the **Browse** button, it will run the **run()** function in javascript.
[image: image-02]

3)After I select my data, the other part of function will do their part. So far so good.
[image: image-03]

4)And then, when I want to browse another .csv file, I click the **Browse** button and once I click it, JQuery reload() will be activated and the previous things inside the div will be cleared automatically while I select another csv file. The problem arise when I select another csv file. The page won't run the run() in the javascript.
[image: image-04]

5)And nothing came out from the reloaded page. Why is it like that? Is there any explanation? Can someone help me on this matter?
[image: image-05]

Comment: Point of note: `location.reload()` is nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: try to add `return false` to your click function.. if you see a different result it is because the page is rendering by your server - which would explain the "empty" result page (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462143/prevent-default-on-form-submit-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to clear the previously selected file when browsing for new one.

Replace this:

```
location.reload();
```

by this:

```
$(this).val("");
```

**[Here is the JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y1ju8ob5/)**

Clearing the value of the control would suffice instead of reloading the page(which causes the events attached initially to be lost, even though your browse window is open)

Comment: Well, your answer didn't really hit what I'm asking for, but you did help me in another part and you inspired me to do it the other way round :D

Comment: @J.Bond Glad I could help Mr.Bond! :D

Answer (score 0):

I've found how to do it.

```
$('#csv_file_upload').click(function() {
    $(this).val("");
    if($("#data-display").length > 0) {
        console.log("Delete yo");
         $("#data-display" ).remove();
    }
```

I first delete the specific tag and then I use the appendTo() to make a new  tag in other part of the code. And then I add the data to the new  tag :)