# Page not redirecting to stripe checkout after it passed form validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am using HTML 5 required attribute for form validation. Now what I want is that if the form has passed the HTML 5 validation, it should take the user to the stripe checkout (I deliberately xxx out info in the code below for SO question).

Now if the form has not passed validation, the submit doesn't process, which is good. But after I complete the form and submit the form, it does not take me to the stripe checkout page, it just refreshes the page. What am I doing wrong?

```
<form id="tcform">

<p><b>Quantity:</b> 1</p>
<b class="price">Price:</b> <s>£xx</s> <span style="color: red;">£xx</span>
<button class="btn btn-default buynow" id="checkout-button-sku_xxx" role="link">
     Buy Now
    </button>
    <p>
    <i style="font-size:small">Limited time offer</i>
    </p>

  <p class="tcparagraph">
  <input id="field_terms" type="checkbox" required name="terms"> I accept the <u><a href="Terms" id="tclink">Terms and Conditions</a></u></p>

  <div id="error-message"></div>
  </form>

<script>
    (function() {

        var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxx');

        var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-sku_xxx');

        checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
            // them to Checkout.

            const isFormValid = checkoutButton.form.checkValidity();

            if(isFormValid==true) {

            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                    items: [{
                        sku: 'sku_xxx',
                        quantity: 1
                    }],

                    // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
                    // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
                    // a successful payment.
                    // Instead use one of the strategies described in
                    // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment
                    successUrl: window.location.protocol + '//metis-online.com/courses/course-BRFAITC009-order-confirmation',
                    cancelUrl: window.location.protocol + '//metis-online.com/order-cancelled',
                })
                .then(function(result) {
                    if (result.error) {
                        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                        // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
                        var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
                        displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: You are checking validity of the form as soon as the script is loaded. My guess is the form is invalid at that point and you never actually set the event listener.

Comment: @mlibby Can you show me example code so I can see what you mean and mark your answer please :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to prevent the **default behaviour** of submiting the form. So do:

```
checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

...

if(isFormValid==true) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

### References

- [Prevent Default on Form Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462143/prevent-default-on-form-submit-jquery)
- [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 2):

Right now your code is only attaching the `click` listener if the form is valid at page load. In the absence of other form behavior, clicking a button in a form submits it back to the page it came from, which is why it looks like a page refresh.

You need to move the form check inside the button click event handler like so:

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxx');
        var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-sku_xxx');

        checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if($('#tcform')[0].checkValidity()){

                // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
                // them to Checkout.
                stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                    items: [{
                        sku: 'sku_xxx',
                        quantity: 1
                    }],

                    // Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
                    // purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
                    // a successful payment.
                    // Instead use one of the strategies described in
                    // https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment
                    successUrl: window.location.protocol + '//www.xxx.com',
                    cancelUrl: window.location.protocol + '//www.xxx.com',
                })
                .then(function(result) {
                    if (result.error) {
                        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                        // error, display the localized error message to your customer.
                        var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
                        displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
  })();
```

But it might be even better to listen to the form's `submit` event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event):

```
$('#tcform').on('submit', function() {
     stripe.redirectToCheckout({ 
         ...
     });
});
```

The `submit` event is only emitted after the form is validated.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I've tried your solution and a lot of other methds. Let me update my code

Comment: I changed it to try via button for now but can't see what I'm doing incorrect. Maybe it's same issue because of my lack of understanding. I'm not a full time developer, just writing a little code for a simple webpage :)

Answer (score 1):

It happened to us as well.

We've added the [`novalidate` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp) (removes the HTML5 validation) to the form and validate it by javascript only.

```html
    <form id="tcform" novalidate>
    ...
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

[As Jannes Botis said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60725068/2828611), you can use `preventDefault`. You can also just return `false` on the eventHandler from an `submit` event, that will also cancel the form submission. For reference see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-to-use-preventdefault-vs-return-false-in-javascript/