# Laravel AJAX response loads wrong route/window

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

**I have two routes:**

```
Route::get('/download/{hash}','DownloadController@exists')->name('exists');
Route::post('/download/{hash}','DownloadController@verify')->name('verify');
```

**Procedure:**

Basically the user enters a `URL` e.g. `localhost/download/56iq45agosasa` the first route is called and the `download.blade.php` view is shown. There is a form, where the user has to input a password and when the submit button is clicked, an `ajax` request is sent to the second (post) route.

The `DownloadController@verify` returns the json but displays it in a blank window (see screenshot) But it should be returned in the `download.blade.php` view. 
[image]

Somehow the form disappears and the ajax success function is not called.

**Code snippets Download.blade.php:**

```
@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form method="POST">
                <label for="uploadPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="uploadPassword" placeholder="Password" required="">
                <button id="btn-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-2">Submit</button>
                {{ csrf_field() }}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@push('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".btn-submit").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        let password = $("input[name=password]").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"",
            data:{
                password:password
            },
            success:function(data){
                console.log("I don't get shown");
                //alert(data.success + " " + data.matches);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
@endpush
```

**DownloadController:**

```
class DownloadController extends Controller
{
public function exists(Request $request, $hash)
{

    // Some private mysql queries

    // Return the hash to the download view
    return view('download',[
        'hash' => $hash
    ]);
}

public function verify(Request $request, $hash)
{
    return response()->json(
        ['success'=>'Got Simple Ajax Request.']
    );
}
}
```

Comment: If `@push('scripts')`  pushes to scripts on the top of your page you should wrap that script in a `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` to ensure you're attaching the listener at a time where it actually exists. Also, a form submit handler is generally better practice since forms can be submitted without clicking the submit under certain circumstances

Comment: okay thank you! So; I should remove the button on submit listener (deactivate it) and add a form submit listener instead?

Comment: yes. That way you can also capture someone typing in a password and pressing {enter} which is a common thing to do

Comment: @apokryfos It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot. As you helped me to solve it, if you want write a short answer so that I can mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two things that will help improve this code:

- Wrap the listener in a `document.ready` function to ensure it's attached when the button is available in the page. This is necessary if `@push` will make the script end up above the form declaration in the page.
- Listen for the form submit event so you can capture the submit via any of the possible ways that one can submit a form (e.g. by pressing ENTER on an input)

```
@push('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () {
    $("form").on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        let password = $("input[name=password]").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"",
            data:{
                password:password
            },
            success:function(data){
                console.log("I don't get shown");
                //alert(data.success + " " + data.matches);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the form gets submitted. 
Instead of overriding button click with your jQuery function, use it to change submit handler like so

[Prevent Default on Form Submit jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462143/prevent-default-on-form-submit-jquery)

Make sure you put id on the form.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? I now let the form return false on submit but nothing happens