# How to prevent form submission when invoked by HTMLFormElement.submit()

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've found that when trying to prevent form submission that I thought I could use `event.preventDefault()` via the regular `onsubmit` event listener.

This method does work for when the form is submitted either by hitting the Enter key within a form's input, or by pressing the form's submit button.

I found that it was *not* prevented when the form was triggered with [`HTMLFormElement.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit), when I was doing some tests in the browser to see how I could exploit it.

I was surprised to see that this submit method doesn't trigger an event, effectively allowing someone within the client to bypass any form validation, either be it imposed via HTML or JS.

How can I prevent form submission when triggered by `HTMLFormElement.submit()` ?

Here's an example ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/lvl99/pen/abdvMOO?editors=1010)):

```html
<script>
var $form = document.getElementById("my-form");
var $input = document.getElementById("restricted-input");
var $notice = document.getElementById("notice");
var $submitForm = document.getElementById("submit-form");
var $requestSubmitForm = document.getElementById("request-submit-form");
var $resetForm = document.getElementById("reset-form");

$form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $notice.innerHTML = "Submitted: " + $input.value;
});

$submitForm.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $notice.innerHTML = "";
  $form.submit();
});

$requestSubmitForm.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $notice.innerHTML = "";
  $form.requestSubmit();
});

$resetForm.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $notice.innerHTML = "";
  $form.reset();
});
</script>

<form id="my-form" action="/" method="post">
  <input id="restricted-input" type="text" pattern="^[a-z]+$" required />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<p id="notice"></p>

<p>
  <a id="submit-form" href="javascript:void 0">form.submit()</a><br/>
  <a id="request-submit-form" href="javascript:void 0">form.requestSubmit()</a><br/>
  <a id="reset-form" href="javascript:void 0">Reset form</a>
</p>
```

Edit: Please read the question in its entirety before answering. Answers that mention jQuery, `onsubmit` or `event.preventDefault()` as part of the resolution will be downvoted.

Comment: If you're explicitly calling the submit method of a form, there's no way to prevent the submission after the call (`e.preventDefault` doesn't do anything, in a submit handler).

Comment: Try to use jQuery, much easier. Here u can see an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462143/prevent-default-on-form-submit-jquery

Comment: @FlamurBeqiraj jQuery is not going to solve the issue here if people can get around the form submission with vanilla JS

Comment: @Teemu so basically anyone can submit any form online if they go into the DevTools console and trigger it with `submit()` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the case, the submit listeners are not even called when triggering form submission in JS.

Comment: Hmmmm, I think istead of using <form>, maybe try to trigger an XHR request that u can control when to be sent. Could this be helpful?

Comment: @FlamurBeqiraj appreciate that you're trying to find a resolution, however the question relates directly to my issue. I am using a `<form>` element and trying to prevent programmatic submission via JS that circumvents form validation and my `onsubmit` event listener.

Comment: @MattScheurich Please don't waste too much of your time to this. It's always possible to post a form (or an AJAX call as well) without validation from a browser, or from a server when the poster doesn't even need your page. Make sure you've proper validation at the server side too, that's the only secure way.

Comment: That's what i tried to say, like in the post of @RupeshTerase sayed, the browser is build like that, so to fully controle that, you can use alternatives.

Comment: @FlamurBeqiraj Validation of an AJAX call is easy to circumvent. Just send it once, and then pick up the call from the Network tab, and use Edit and Resend tool.