# Button input submit not doing

Tags: javascript, html

In all the codes that I wrote, the button does not work. The site simply reloads and that's it. Maybe this is an error not in the code, but in something else, please help
This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="'en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <script>

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = function() {
                    const name = document.querySelectr('#name').value;
                    alert(`Hello, ${name}!`);
                };
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <form>
            <input autofocus id="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
            <input type="submit">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form without `method` will be submit using `GET` by default. Your JS event handler did not prevent default action for the form submit, that's why when you click button and it's just like reload.

Comment: `querySelectr` is a typo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50803477/128761

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Default on Form Submit jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462143/prevent-default-on-form-submit-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a submit button will reload the page to send a request. This can be prevented with [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). Here's an example with your code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
        alert(`Hello, ${name}!`);
    };
});
```

Comment: It doesn't solved

Comment: There was also a typo in `querySelector`, but I've updated my answer. It should now work.

Comment: e.preventDefault() do not need, problem was with missed o is querySelector. Thank you for your answer.